# deploying and retrieving Address settings (State & Country picklists)

Tags: metadata-api, address

I'm having problems understanding how to deploy Address.settings with the Metadata API.  As in:  how do I structure the package.xml?

I have this as Address.settings (shortened for brevity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddressSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <countriesAndStates>
        <countries>
            <active>true</active>
            <integrationValue>Andorra</integrationValue>
            <isoCode>AD</isoCode>
            <label>Andorra</label>
            <orgDefault>false</orgDefault>
            <standard>true</standard>
            <visible>true</visible>
        </countries>
        ....
        </countriesAndStates>
        </AddressSettings>
```

And this is the package.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Address</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

After zipping this up and deploying through the Metadata API in Workbench I get this error:

```
The object 'Address' of type Settings was included in the manifest file package.xml but the associated settings metadata is missing from the 'settings' folder
```

Can you see what is wrong with the package.xml in this case?

Comment: Is `Address.settings` inside a `settings` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens when your directory structure is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
src/
    package.xml
    settings/
        Address.settings
```

Your `package.xml` appears to be correct as written.

Comment: Excellent, knew it was just some minor niggle preventing this from working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

FYI: You can't create new state and country picklist values via Metadata API:

> You can’t use the Metadata API to create or delete new states or
>   countries.
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_addresssettings.htm?search_text=AddressSettings

Real bummer, forcing you to manually create dozens of values via the web interface!

Comment: +1 for relevant information... but a -1 for Salesforce because this answer stinks :[