# Payload error while deploy Address settings (State & Country picklists)

Tags: metadata-api, workbench, package.xml

Using Workbench i have retrieved the Address setting using package.xml

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Address</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

I have downloaded the Zip file and have added some countries in the Address.settings file. When I deployed the file my changes haven't reflected in the org.

[image]

Please help me out.

Also I have referred the below link also [deploying and retrieving Address settings (State & Country picklists)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237636/deploying-and-retrieving-address-settings-state-country-picklists)

This is the result i got in workbench .

Also when check in the deployment status i got Payload error says " No package.xml found"

Comment: Do you know if there were any deployment errors? If you are pushing metadata using Workbench you can also see deployment errors in Salesforce setup (see: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=deploy_monitoring.htm&type=5).

Comment: The second answer on the question you linked to answers this question. You cannot add new Country values via the Metadata API at all; it is not supported. See [`AddressSettings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_addresssettings.htm).

Comment: @DavidReed I am trying to add the States under existing countries .

Comment: @user69942 Please see the call-out box in the linked documentation: "You can’t use the Metadata API to create or delete new states or countries."

Comment: @DavidReed Is there any way to add new countries under the country